# Django ModelForm Unittesting: Populate fields with custom data

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am trying to populate with data a model form with a custom field. However, the foreign key is throwing the error:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
>   choices.

I cannot understand what am I doing wrong:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Name(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Surname(models.Model):
    first_name_key = models.ForeignKey(Name)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from population.models import Surname


class SurnameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta(object):
        model = Surname
        fields = ['first_name_key', 'last_name', 'age']
```

This is how I try to populate the modelform:

```
>> from population.models import Name, Surname
>> from population.forms import SurnameForm
>> f_name = Name(first_name='George')
>> model_data = {'first_name_key': f_name, 'id': 1, 'last_name': 'Taras', 'age': 2}
>> form = SurnameForm(model_data)
>> form.is_valid()
False
>> form.errors
{'first_name_key': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

---

FInally, the following code is working as expected:

```
>> from population.models import Name, Surname
>> from population.forms import SurnameForm
>> f_name = Name(first_name='George')
>> f_name.save()
>> model_data = {'first_name_key': f_name.pk, 'last_name': 'Taras', 'age': 2}
>> form = SurnameForm(model_data)
>> form.is_valid()
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass the id keyword, that's optional. Instead of passing f_name pass it's primary key as f_name.pk:

```
model_data = {'first_name_key': f_name.pk, 'last_name': 'Taras', 'age': 2}``
```

And by the way, that seems a weird implementation. Why would you create a model Name. Just curious.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I am not in front of my box right now, but as far as I remember, when I pass the primary key using ```f_name.pk``` I get an error stating that the value should be an instance of the model ```Name``` which, by the way, is a moque of a more complex construction! I will have to test it however, and I will report back.

Comment: Thats correct, I thought more about it at I think you have to pass model_data as a kwargs argument. I updated my answer accordingly. but I'll test when I'm in front of my box.

Comment: Passig the model_data as **kwargs results in error ```TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'age'```. The first solution works as expected.

Comment: I'll roll it back now